# Functions of double pointer array doesn't work

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, pointers, dereference

I wrote this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printAllStrings(char **arrPP[])
{
    for (char ***p = arrPP; **p != NULL; ++p)
    {
        int z = 0;
        while (*(*p + z) != NULL)
        {
            printf("%s ", *(*p + z));
            z++;
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}
void maxLengthString(char **arrPP[])
{
    int max = 0;
    for (char ***c = arrPP; **c != NULL; ++c)
    {
        int counter = 0;
        int z = 0;
        while (*(*c + z) != NULL)
        {
            counter++;
            z++;
            if (counter > max)
                max = counter;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", max);
}

int main()
{
    char *arrP1[] = {"father", "mother", NULL};
    char *arrP2[] = {"sister", "brother", "grandfather", NULL};
    char *arrP3[] = {"grandmother", NULL};
    char *arrP4[] = {"uncle", "aunt", NULL};
    char **arrPP[] = {arrP1, arrP2, arrP3, arrP4, NULL};

    maxLengthString(arrPP);
    printAllStrings(arrPP);
    return 0;
}
```

printAllStrings prints all the arrays that arrPP points at and maxLengthString(char **arrPP[] )should return the longest array.
I couldd't return the longest array so I tried to print the max value of length.
the output should be:

```
father mother
sister brother grandfather
grandmother
uncle aunt
3
```

or

```
father mother
sister brother grandfather
grandmother
uncle aunt
arrP2 // cause it's the longest array
```

but nothing is printed why is that?And how could I return the longest array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters the both for loops

```
for (char ***p = arrPP; **p != NULL; ++p)
```

and

```
for (char ***c = arrPP; **c != NULL; ++c)
```

are incorrect. Elements of the passed to the functions arrays have the type `char **`. Thus conditions in the loops shall look like

```
for (char ***p = arrPP; *p != NULL; ++p)
```

and

```
for (char ***c = arrPP; *c != NULL; ++c)
```

Also the if statement within this while loop

```
    while (*(*c + z) != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        z++;
        if (counter > max)
            max = counter;
    }
```

must be moved outside the loop

```
    while (*(*c + z) != NULL)
    {
        counter++;
        z++;
    }
    if (counter > max)
        max = counter;
```

And you should add the new line character `'\n'` in this call of `printf`

```
printf("%d\n", max);
```

Answer (score 1):

The conditions `**p != NULL` and `**c != NULL` are wrong and they can dereference `NULL` without checking. They should be `*p != NULL` and `*c != NULL` to check if what are pointed at by `p` and `c` are `NULL`.

Also the order to call the functions `maxLengthString` and `printAllStrings` should be swapped to get the desired output.